# cannot resolve method 'getExternalStoragePublicDirectory'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to save the captured image but got an error like the title.

```
private File createPhotoFile(){
        File storageDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES +"/sidentanpic/");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(storageDir)));
        try{
            if(storageDir.exists()){
                System.out.println("Folder tersedia");
            }else{
                storageDir.mkdir();
                System.out.println("Folder telah dibuat");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File image =null;
        try{
            image = File.createTempFile(name,".jpg", storageDir);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Failed","Gagal menyimpan "+ e.toString());
        }
        return image;
    }
```

should I add something in AndroidManifest?

Comment: `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is a method on `Environment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is static method in `Environment` class. So, please try as below:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()
```

But, This method is deprecated in Android Q version. Please check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) for more info on this.